# High voltage in electrical grid and Inverter's voltage output range

Tags: inverter

I have an 24 V inverter. In the manual i've read that this inverter will bypass the electrical grid voltage in the range 170V-280V.

So with other words , when the electrical grid's voltage goes (for some problem) to 280V , this inverter will output this voltage to my devices connected with it.
On its manual , i've read that this inverter is suitable for all the home/office Devices.
This is very strange , because if the voltage is 280V , appliances like TV,Computers,... will be damaged.

My question is that if I am correct with my logic and these kind of inverters should not be purchased , or i'm wrong and there's something that i don't understand with the inverter's output's range ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the inverter is also a battery charger, and will charge the batteries when grid power is available, as well as passing grid power to the connected load.

If that is the case, it is quite reasonable for the inverter to pass whatever voltage it receives to the load.  The load is no more likley to be damaged by high voltage than if it was connected directly to the grid.

If you had given the inverter make and model, I would have been able to confirm my assumptions.

Comment: The inverter is PowerWalker 3000 PSW. Yes it is also a battery charger. But why the inverter confirm that it is suitable for all home/office appliances and also confirm that will output the voltage 170-280V that comes from electrical grid ? Because if i connect my TV directly to electrical grid , when 280V is coming my tv will be broken so a good inverter that claim to be suitable for my home devices , should not let passing a voltage that can damage that device.

Comment: This is just an inverter/charger, not an AC voltage regulator.  If AC input power is available, the inverter simply passes that power, unchanged, to the output.  If you want something to protect your appliances from overvoltage, you need an AC voltage regulator or power conditioner.

Comment: It's not clear from the manual, but I suspect that the unit will switch to inverter mode if the input voltage is outside the 170 - 280 volt range.

Comment: What i don't understand is why this inverter doesn't switch to battery mode when the voltage is outside 190-240 V , so the devices will be protected. Is this so difficult to have a narrow voltage range , instead of this wide range 170-240 V ? Why these manufacturers choose to have a wide output voltage range ? Does this means a poor design of the device ?